# Get current user in a model in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activeadmin

I am using ActiveAdmin. I need to store the User that created or updated every record.

So I added user_created_id and user_updated_id to every model. 
On before_save I want to store the information about current_admin_user. The problem is that I cannot access current_admin_user in a model.

Is there a way to do that without breaking MVC?

I found this: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models
But I am not sure if it is safe.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Do it in controller (it's the reason that controller exist) before save:

```
def create
  @my_model = MyModel.create params[:my_model]
  @my_model.user_created = current_user
  @my_model.save
end
```

The same with the `update` method.

Comment: I am using ActiveAdmin, which means that I am using ActiveAdmin controllers.